# Группировка и агрегация в запросах к PostgreSQL в Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Столкнулся с проблемой, наверное синтаксиса, запроса к PostgreSQL в Python.

Ошибка:

```
AmbiguousFunction                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-ad82da23eca4> in <module>
     29             THEN 'middle'
     30             ELSE 'unknown'
---> 31             END''')
     32 colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
     33 records = cursor.fetchall()

AmbiguousFunction: function avg(unknown) is not unique
LINE 8:         END ages_type, AVG('Pay Rate')
                               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Цель: получить средню зарплату по сотрудникам, разбитым на возрастные группы, обращаясь к PostgreSQL в Python.
Таблица содержит 2 поля:

```
age: [30,34,31,32,30,30,33,33,31,39,63,38,32,46,31,34,31,29,33,33]

Pay Rate: [28.5,23.0,29.0,21.5,16.56,20.5,55.0,55.0,34.95,34.95,80.0,65.0,43.0,48.5,40.1,34.0,40.0,35.5,41.0,42.75]
```

Необходимо сгруппировать age по возрастам:

- до 33 (junior)
- от 33 до 99 (midle)

и для каждой группы рассчитать средний показатель Pay Rate

Делаю через case, но python ругается на синтаксис, подскажите пожалуйста где може быть ошибка. Нашел примеры где этот код работает при обращении к БД в терминале, но в Python не пашет

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT
       CASE
            WHEN age <= 33
            THEN 'junior'
            WHEN age > 33
            THEN 'middle'
            ELSE 'unknown'
        END ages_type, AVG('Pay Rate')
FROM hr_dataset
GROUP BY
        CASE
            WHEN age <= 33
            THEN 'junior'
            WHEN age > 33
            THEN 'middle'
            ELSE 'unknown'
            END''')
```

В результате должна получится табличка, с колонками:

- Type
- AVG_pay_rate

Где в Type будут указаны группы возрастов, в а AVG_pay_rate средний показатьль  из pay_rate

Comment: Функция AVG возвращает среднее значение. Это математическая функция. Как вы представляете ее вычисление для строки ?

Comment: Напоминаю - строки в одинарных кавычках, названия столбцов в двойных ...

Comment: ахах, так и знал что где то с кавычками косяк ))) спасибо большое, поменял 'Pay Rate' на "Pay Rate" и заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в кавычках, поменял AVG('Pay Rate') на AVG("Pay Rate") и заработало. Спасибо Mike!

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT
       CASE
            WHEN age <= 33
            THEN 'junior'
            WHEN age > 33
            THEN 'middle'
            ELSE 'unknown'
        END ages_type, AVG("Pay Rate")
FROM hr_dataset
GROUP BY
        CASE
            WHEN age <= 33
            THEN 'junior'
            WHEN age > 33
            THEN 'middle'
            ELSE 'unknown'
            END''')
```